# Calculate difference between dates returning datetime result

Tags: t-sql

I need to get the difference between two dates in datetime format: `HH:mm:ss`. Is it possible using some T-SQL function? I always used `DATEDIFF` but it returns only `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare @date1 datetime = '2012-08-04 12:10'
declare @date2 datetime = '2012-08-04 13:10'

select cast(@date2 - @date1 as time(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply substract them to get a datetime value, then format this how you want.

e.g.

```
select CONVERT(varchar(100), getdate(), 108)
```

where you would replace `getdate()` with the result of your subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

If the elapsed time exceeds 24 hours, the result will be misleading (the "mod" of 24:00:00). This snippet will include the number of days as a prefix to the time.  I have included calculating both a forward and backward interval.

```
declare @date1 datetime,@date2 datetime
set @date1 = '2013-01-02 12:01:02' 
set @date2 = '2013-01-03 22:00:00' 
select 

   -- forward interval
   case when datediff(dd,@date1,@date2) != 0 then
    cast(datediff(dd,@date1,@date2) as varchar)
    + 'd ' + convert(varchar(100), @date1-@date2, 108)
   else
      convert(varchar(100), @date1-@date2, 108)
   end as ElapsedT1,

   -- backward interval
   case when datediff(dd,@date2,@date1) != 0 then
    cast(datediff(dd,@date2,@date1) as varchar)
    + 'd ' + convert(varchar(100), @date2-@date1, 108)
   else
      convert(varchar(100), @date2-@date1, 108)
   end as ElapsedT2

ElapsedT1     ElapsedT2
1d 14:01:02   -1d 09:58:58
```